# How to differentiate errors in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, validation, error-handling, bootstrap-modal

I've created a two modals on one page. One for login and second for register. Unfortunately, after validation $error name's are the same so script open two modals at one time.

**Any ideas how to open register/login modal after validation?**

To open modal I use this code:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <script>myModal.show();</script>
@endif
```

but it do not recognizes from which modal it error.

```
@error('password')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: You can solve your problem by specifying a name for each validation bag , check this out on docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags)

Answer (score 0):

You can name different error bags.
Check out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags for more info.